# Need help to format output

Tags: c, output

Problem is written below the code with output screen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    int i,j,x,n,count;
   char no[100],no1[100];
   printf("Enter an array of numbers:- ");
   scanf("%s",no);
   strcpy(no1,no);
   x = strlen(no);
   for(i=0;i<x;i++)
   {
    count = 0;
    for(j=0;j<x;j++)
    {
        if(no[i]==no1[j])
            count++ ;
      }
    printf("\n\nFrequency of %c is %d",no[i],count);
   }
   getch();
}
```

Output:

```
Enter an array of numbers:- 17485112


Frequency of 1 is 3

Frequency of 7 is 1

Frequency of 4 is 1

Frequency of 8 is 1

Frequency of 5 is 1

Frequency of 1 is 3

Frequency of 1 is 3

Frequency of 2 is 1
```

/** so the problem is it displays the occurance of each and every digit of the string. What I want is it should neglect the repeated digits.
    E.g. here 1 has frequency 3 and same line(Frequency of 1 is 3) is repeated 3 times.
    So I don't want it to repeat.

First I did this

```
\\ if(no[i]!=no[i-1])
        printf("\n\nFrequency of %c is %d",no[i],count);
```

It works if repeated digits are consecutive but not otherwise

Then I tried

```
\\for(n=0;n<i;n++)
\\{ 
\\if(no[i]!=no[i-n])
    printf("\n\nFrequency of %c is %d",no[i],count);
```

Solution:-

I arranged the string in ascending order and the used the following thing

```
if(no[i]!=no[i-1])
            printf("\n\nFrequency of %c is %d",no[i],count);
```

Output:

Enter an array of numbers:- 1236665554447182999352000

Frequency of 0 is 3

Frequency of 1 is 2

Frequency of 2 is 3

Frequency of 3 is 2

Frequency of 4 is 3

Frequency of 5 is 4

Frequency of 6 is 3

Frequency of 7 is 1

Frequency of 8 is 1

Frequency of 9 is 3

Comment: Your outermost loop should iterate through all possible digits (0 to 9) and not through the elements of the string.

Comment: Thanks guys...
Solution found. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 x = strlen(no);
 int number_count[10] ={0};   
 int i=0,j=0;
 for(i=0;i<x;i++)
 {
   for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
      if(no[i] -'0' ==j)
        number_count[j]++;
 }
 for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
   if(number_count[j] != 0)
      printf("\n\nFrequency of %c is %d",j,number_count[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the n[i] list such that

   ```
   n[i] = 1, 7, 4, 8, 5, 1, 1, 2
   ```

   appears as,

   ```
   n[i] = 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8
   ```
2. Now use count to count the number of occurrences, you can do google for that.
3. finally use,

   ```
   if(no[i]!=no[i-1])
   {
      printf("\n\nFrequency of %c is %d",no[i],count);
   }
   ```

In other words, use binary search algorithm.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Nice answer! Binary search it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
int i,x,count;
char numbers[100];
int noofoccurance[10]={0};
printf("Enter an array of numbers:- ");
scanf("%s",numbers);
x = strlen(no);
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
  a[no[i]-48] = a[no[i]-48]+1;
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if[noofoccurance[i]!=0]
    printf(\nFrequency of %d is %d",i,noofoccurance[i])
 }
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:
keep the processed element a new array and before processing a new element check whether the element present in new array. If it is available skip the process for that element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main()
    {
    int i,j,x,n,count;
    char no[100],no1[100];
    printf("Enter an array of numbers:- ");
    scanf("%s",no);
    strcpy(no1,no);
    x = strlen(no);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
    count = 0;
    for(j=0;j<x;j++)
    {
      if(no[i]==no1[j])
          {
              count++ ;
              no1[j] = 0.1;
          }
    }
    if(count!=0)
    printf("\n\nFrequency of %c is %d",no[i],count);
    }
    getch();
    }
```